# Userform visibility

Tags: excel, userform, vba

My userform opens other workbooks but then remains over them. Can this be stopped? This also happens when clicking between open workbooks.
the code below works for me when activating a different sheet but not a different workbook.

```
    Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
If Sh.Name <> "HTFD" And Flight_Deck.Visible = True Then
    Unload Flight_Deck
End If
If Sh.Name = "HTFD" And Flight_Deck.Visible = False Then
    Flight_Deck.Show vbModeless

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Clarification required: Is this sample code your attempt to hide/remove the userform when not on the specified page in the specified workbook? Do you want to completely unload the userform, or are you just looking for a way to "hide" it? Or would you prefer to keep the userform visible, but able to be covered by other workbooks?

Comment: Yes you are spot on. It was my feeble attempt to hide the userform. Ideally it would only show over one sheet in one workbook and be covered when switching to any other workbook. Thank you very much in advance for your help, Mistella.

Answer (score 1):

Since you were using code in the `Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)`, I'm assuming you know how to insert code into the `ThisWorkbook` Module. As well as the `Workbook_SheetActivate` there are also subs for the workbook activation and deactivation events.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    If Sh.Name = "HTFD" Then
        Flight_Deck.Show vbModeless
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
    Flight_Deck.Hide
End Sub
```

You should also be able to insert code into the module for a particular sheet. If you do that, you could use the following code in the sheet module for which you want the userform to show, and since the code would only be activated when *that* particular sheet is activated, you won't have to do a check on the sheet's name. *(The check on the sheet's name is required for the `workbook_Activate` code because that runs whenever the workbook is activated, not just for a particular sheet.)*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Flight_Deck.Show vbModeless
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    Flight_Deck.Hide
End Sub
```

Of course, with this setup, the userform will **always** be visible on that sheet in that workbook whenever anyone opens it. If you only want to initialize the userform after other code has ran, and/or you want to specifically close the userform at times; you should check if the userform is currently loaded.

This code was posted by gijsmo *(April 24th, 2011, 14:08)* on [ozgrid.com](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/96544-test-if-a-specific-userform-is-loaded?p=734770#post734770) (response #2)

```
Function IsUserFormLoaded(ByVal UFName As String) As Boolean
  Dim UForm As Object

  IsUserFormLoaded = False
  For Each UForm In VBA.UserForms
    If UForm.Name = UFName Then
      IsUserFormLoaded = True
      Exit For
    End If
  Next
End Function 'IsUserFormLoaded
```

---

**Explanation**

---

Using the `Flight_Deck.Hide`/`Flight_Deck.Show` combination should retain any information on the userform for when it's shown next. *Exception:* if the code is paused/stopped in between hiding and showing i.e. for debugging, the information will be lost.

`Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()` and `Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()` are triggered when the active worksheet changes, but the active workbook does not. `Private Sub Workbook_Activate()` and `Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()` are triggered only when the active workbook changes. When either `Private Sub Workbook_Activate()` or `Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()` are triggered, then **neither** `Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()` nor `Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()` are activated.

Thus, since you only want the userform to show over one particular sheet in one particular workbook, you will need code in both places.

Also, with this logic, I don't *think* it's necessary to check the status of `Flight_Deck.Visible`; however, I could be wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I'm so glad I've joined 'Team Stack'.